# PolymerElements API reference?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-elements

Where can I find a full API reference for [PolymerElements](https://www.webcomponents.org/author/PolymerElements)?

For example, [the description for PaperDialogBehavior](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior) says

> Use the *dialog-dismiss* and *dialog-confirm* attributes on interactive controls to close the dialog. If the user dismisses the dialog with *dialog-confirm*, the `closingReason` will update to include `confirmed: true`.

But I can't find any further information anywhere about what `closingReason` actually is (a property? a parameter passed to some callback?) and how it "includes" `confirmed: true`.

Instead of wasting time on guessing how to do every single little thing when using Polymer, it would be nice to have an actual API reference. Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any further information. Documentation isn't well written and you have to find many things on your own. Just remember that everything in Polymer is about properties. So `closingReson` is property that you can access on `paper-dialog` (or any other elements using `paperDialogBehavior`).

This property contains object `{confirmed: true|false}`

Truly said, behaviors has extremely badly written documentations. It is very confusing. For example:

> modal: boolean = false
>   If modal is true, this implies `no-cancel-on-outside-click`, `no-cancel-on-esc-key` and `with-backdrop`.

but none of those properties are specified in `paperDialogBehavior`, because it is inherited from `iron-overlay-behavior`. And these inheritences are not documented (mostly).

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that `closingReason` is an attribute Object with a `confirmed` field (and a `dismissed` field that I can't figure out what it means). I'm really surprised that the documentation is so bad, considering Polymer is backed by Google... oh well, `console.log()` to the rescue ;)

Comment: yup.. Polymer's developers aren't the best ones. They don't comunnicate much and also don't care about previous versions of Polymer. The only luck is that it's open source and you can always take a look into source code (which i am doing daily) .. I also had to rewrite few native Polymer elements and fix few bugs on my own. So it is not that great Framework, but it's easy to use and easy to understand